# Servicio OnStart o Onsleep Xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, servicio, android-intent, background

Estoy intentado crear mi primer servicio, he leído mucha documentación (no me he entrado de mucho), he logrado encontrar un video donde explica bastante bien el tema, el problema es que es de hace años (2016), he seguido todos los pasos pero me sale un error **"Service Intent must be explicit: Intent"**, he deducido después de mucho mirar que las versiones de Android han aumentado su seguridad y por eso este tipo o esta forma que indica el video ya no es valida (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7ddaqW1QaY&ab_channel=JocheOjeda).

Mi pregunta es la siguiente ¿Cómo puedo hacer para crear un servicio en Android y me funcione correctamente?
Necesito que se ejecute tanto en la app activa como cuando esta onsleep (necesito que Android no la mate) para que continúe mandando las coordenadas GPS a una BBDD (esta parte la tengo como una tarea secundaria funcionando actualmente, pero el movil la mata cada x tiempo dependiendo del modelo de movil y versión de Android)

El código donde salta el error:

```
protected override void OnStart()
   {
        base.OnStart();

        var servicioPruebaint = new Intent("com.xamarin.ServicesDemo1");
        servicioPrueba_Connexion = new ServicioPrueba_Connexion(this);
        BindService(servicioPruebaint, servicioPrueba_Connexion, Bind.AutoCreate); //en esta línea salta el error en debug
        }
```

y donde creo que realmente esta el error:

```
 [Service]
    [IntentFilter (new String[] {"com.xamarin.ServicesDemo1"})]

    public class ServicioPrueba : Service
    {
```

Ahora mismo el servicio lo tengo preparado para que me imprima por pantalla un numero sumando cada 10 segundos, pero como no logro que se ejecute en el simulador ni en un movil viejo que tengo, no puedo probar que funcione correctamente, pero compilar si que compila.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He localizado este video que hace poco han subido (08/02/2021, he tenido mucha suerte) que la verdad explica muy bien como preparar el servicio en mi caso, he realizado el proceso que el indica y he enlazado el código que tenia en la tarea, de momento llevo 24h con el servicio en marcha y funciona correctamente sin que Android 11 - 10 - 9 - 8 lo cierren.

La pega de el sistema que el indica es que las versiones anteriores a la 8, no compila en la línea del código de la definición del canal de notificación del servicio:

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ServicioChannel", "XXXXXX", NotificationImportance.Max);
```

Aun estoy tratando de solucionarlo, pero de momento lo que hecho es parchearlo, con un try catch si funciona continua si falla lanza la tarea que ya tenia hecha.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikrGq4fvaBo&t=637s&ab_channel=RicardoJosue